# range of two projections

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

If $p,q $ are two projections in $B(H)$ with $dim(pH)=dim(qH)$,then $p$ is equivalent to $q$.
How to construct $v\in B(H)$ such that $p=v^*v,q=vv^*$by using the o.n.b of $pH$ and $qH$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pick orthonormal bases $(e_i)_{i\in I}$ and $(f_i)_{i\in I}$ of $pH$ and $qH$ respectively.  Extend $(e_i)_{i\in I}$ to an orthonormal basis $(e_j)_{j\in J}$ of $H$, so that $I\subset J$.  Define $v:H\to H$ by linear extension of 
\begin{align*}
v(e_j)=\left\{\begin{array}{lcl}
f_j &:&j\in I\\
0 & : & \text{otherwise.}
\end{array}\right.
\end{align*}

Comment: By the above construction,I can show that $V^*V=P$,how to prove $VV^*=q$?

Comment: It should be essentially the same proof.

Comment: But $V^*(f_j)$ is not defined.

Comment: We have $v^*(f_j)=\delta_{ij}e_i$.

Comment: According to your result,we need the assumption that  $e_i \perp f_j$ when $i\neq j$,but pH may not be perpendicular to qH.

Comment: We need no such assumption.  We need $e_i\perp e_j$ for $i\neq j$ (and similarly for the $f_i$), but we are assuming this.